# transact SQL issues with amount of time

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

```
      SELECT
 s.ColID1
,s.ColIdentification2
,s.StatusColumn
,(SELECT
     MAX(pd.DateColumn)
   FROM DocumentTable pd
   WHERE pd.IsPresent = 1
   AND pd.ColIdentification2 = s.ColIdentification2
   AND pd.TypeofFile = 'TextFiles')
 AS maxDate
,(SELECT TOP 1
     u.Title
   FROM DocumentTable pd
   LEFT OUTER JOIN [User] u
     ON u.UserId = pd.UserId
   WHERE pd.IsPresent = 1
   AND pd.ColIdentification2 = s.ColIdentification2
   AND pd.TypeofFile = 'Text Files'
   ORDER BY pd.DateColumn DESC)
 AS Name1
 ,(SELECT TOP 1
     pd.DocumentType
   FROM DocumentTable pd
   WHERE pd.IsPresent = 1
   AND pd.ColIdentification2 = s.ColIdentification2
   AND pd.TypeofFile = 'Text Files'
   ORDER BY pd.DateColumn DESC)
, (SELECT TOP 1
     pd.TypeofFile
   FROM DocumentTable pd
   WHERE pd.IsPresent = 1
   AND pd.ColIdentification2 = s.ColIdentification2
   AND pd.TypeofFile = 'Text Files'
   ORDER BY pd.DateColumn DESC)
 ,(SELECT TOP 1
    pd.Region
    FROM DocumentTable pd
   WHERE pd.IsPresent = 1
   AND pd.ColIdentification2 = s.ColIdentification2
   AND pd.TypeofFile = 'Text Files'
   ORDER BY pd.DateColumn DESC)
 ,(SELECT TOP 1
    pd.Agency 
    FROM DocumentTable pd
   WHERE pd.IsPresent = 1
   AND pd.ColIdentification2 = s.ColIdentification2
   AND pd.TypeofFile = 'Text Files'
   ORDER BY pd.DateColumn DESC)
FROM Service s (NOLOCK)
--left outer join DocumentTable pd1 (NOLOCK)
--on pd1.ColIdentification2 = s.ColIdentification2
WHERE s.IsPresent = 1
--AND pd1.ColIdentification2 = s.ColIdentification2
AND s.StatusColumn IN ('Val1', 'Val3')
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT
   pd.DocumentTableId
 FROM DocumentTable pd
 WHERE pd.IsPresent = 1
 AND pd.ColIdentification2 = s.ColIdentification2
 AND pd.TypeofFile IN ('DC1', 'DC2'))
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT
   utds.ID
 FROM  utds
 WHERE utds.Service_x0020_ID1_Id = s.ColID1
 AND utds.Type IN ('DC1', 'DC2'))
ORDER BY s.ColID1
```

I am trying to optimize this sql. Due to the many subqueries, it is taking a long time. This query is taking more than 10 minutes to run and i am trying to improve on it. Anyway to avoid subqueries. I have tried using Left Outer join between the tables, but I think due to the duplication of data for the ColID1 in the DocumentTable, I am not getting correct data

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tune a query w/o having statistics and execution plan and try and error.

What I think is, you can make it better by converting sub-queries to join. So try to eliminate sub-queries.

You can get rid of 4 joins using below query

```
SELECT s.ColID1
    , s.ColIdentification2
    , s.StatusColumn
    , pd.DocumentType, pd.TypeofFile, pd.Region, pd.TypeofFile, Region
from [Service] s 
    outer apply (select top 1 DocumentType, TypeofFile, Region, TypeofFile, Region
                from DocumentTable
                where IsPresent = 1 and TypeofFile = 'Text Files' 
                    and ColIdentification2 = s.ColIdentification2
                order by DateColumn desc) pd
```

if It helped, try using the same approach.

Also make sure you have index on ColIdentification2 field in both tables.

Comment: thanks, We have colIdentification2 field specified as primary Key with clustered index on it. . I will try to create non clustered index on this column on Document Table. I agree with you, I will build with statistics. The resultset was different, when I tried left outer join last time.  , but I will try it with your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Flicker makes a really good point about ensuring your common columns, like ColIdentification2, are indexed. I would also want to verify you have an index on `DocumentTable.DateColumn`.

At any rate...

Things are a little busy there with your query, let's reformat it a little and take a "big picture" look at it:

```
SELECT
 s.ColID1
,s.ColIdentification2
,s.StatusColumn
,(SELECT TOP 1 u.Title         FROM DocumentTable pd LEFT OUTER JOIN [User] u ON u.UserId = pd.UserId WHERE pd.IsPresent = 1 AND pd.ColIdentification2 = s.ColIdentification2 AND pd.TypeofFile = 'Text Files' ORDER BY pd.DateColumn DESC) AS Name1
,(SELECT MAX(pd.DateColumn)    FROM DocumentTable pd WHERE pd.IsPresent = 1 AND pd.ColIdentification2 = s.ColIdentification2 AND pd.TypeofFile = 'TextFiles') AS maxDate
,(SELECT TOP 1 pd.DocumentType FROM DocumentTable pd WHERE pd.IsPresent = 1 AND pd.ColIdentification2 = s.ColIdentification2 AND pd.TypeofFile = 'Text Files' ORDER BY pd.DateColumn DESC)
,(SELECT TOP 1 pd.TypeofFile   FROM DocumentTable pd WHERE pd.IsPresent = 1 AND pd.ColIdentification2 = s.ColIdentification2 AND pd.TypeofFile = 'Text Files' ORDER BY pd.DateColumn DESC)
,(SELECT TOP 1 pd.Region       FROM DocumentTable pd WHERE pd.IsPresent = 1 AND pd.ColIdentification2 = s.ColIdentification2 AND pd.TypeofFile = 'Text Files' ORDER BY pd.DateColumn DESC)
,(SELECT TOP 1 pd.Agency       FROM DocumentTable pd WHERE pd.IsPresent = 1 AND pd.ColIdentification2 = s.ColIdentification2 AND pd.TypeofFile = 'Text Files' ORDER BY pd.DateColumn DESC)
FROM Service s (NOLOCK)
WHERE s.IsPresent = 1
  AND s.StatusColumn IN ('Val1', 'Val3')
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT utds.ID FROM  utds WHERE utds.Service_x0020_ID1_Id = s.ColID1 AND utds.Type IN ('DC1', 'DC2'))
ORDER BY s.ColID1
```

So, the following columns look like they will all end up coming from SAME row in `DocumentTable` pd:

```
pd.DateColumn
pd.DocumentType 
pd.TypeofFile   
pd.Region       
pd.Agency       

note: For pd.DateColumn, your use of max(pd.DateColumn) has the result same
      the sub-select style you're using in the other pd.* columns:
      SELECT TOP 1 pd.DateColumn from ...BLAH BLAH BLAH... order by pd.DateColumn DESC
Also your pd.DateColumn's subselect has a where clause checking for 'TextFiles'
instead of 'Text Files' that the other pd.* columns are using, should they all
be 'Text Files'?  (Note the extra embedded space in 'TextFiles' vs 'Text Files')
```

Instead of running that same sub-query logic 5 different times for pd,
let's push it into a left join and try doing it once...

This is totally untested code btw, I hope it works :-)

```
SELECT
  s.ColID1
, s.ColIdentification2
, s.StatusColumn
/* If we get a stable row for PD pulling u.Title from User becomes easier... */
, (select u.Title from User u where on u.UserId = pd.UserId) as userTitle
, pd.DateColumn
, pd.DocumentType
, pd.TypeofFile
, pd.Region
, pd.Agency
FROM Service s (NOLOCK)
left join DocumentTable pd
       on  pd.IsPresent = 1 
       and pd.ColIdentification2 = s.ColIdentification2
       and pd.TypeofFile = 'Text Files'
       /* This next condition avoids having to do the ORDER BY pd.DateColumnDESC 
        * The idea is for sqlserver to consider all potential matching pd records
        * but ignore any that aren't the largest date.
        */
       and not exists( select 1 from DocumentTable pd2
                       where pd2.IsPresent          = pd1.IsPresent
                         and pd2.ColIdentification2 = pd.ColIdentification2
                         and pd2.TypeofFile         = pd.TypeofFile
                         and pd2.DateColumn         > pd.DateColumn)
       /* may as well add the "no DC1 & DC2" clause here... */
       and not exists (select 1 FROM DocumentTable pd3
                       where pd2.IsPresent          = pd1.IsPresent
                         and pd2.ColIdentification2 = pd.ColIdentification2
                         and pd2.TypeofFile         in ( 'DC1', 'DC2')
                         and pd2.DateColumn         > pd.DateColumn)
WHERE s.IsPresent = 1
  AND s.StatusColumn IN ('Val1', 'Val3')
  AND NOT EXISTS (
     SELECT 1 FROM  utds
     WHERE utds.Service_x0020_ID1_Id = s.ColID1
       AND utds.Type                 IN ('DC1', 'DC2') )
ORDER BY s.ColID1
```

A few closing thoughts:

I like indenting complex `WHERE` clauses, makes it easier for me to wrap my head
around the logic.

To think about the behavior of the query, work with what the main table 's' is doing:

```
select * FROM Service s
```

For each record we get from 's' we'll want to find (at most) one suitable 'pd' record.

Here "suitable" means common columns like `pd.ColIdentification2 = s.colIdentification` and so on.

The subtle part is this:

```
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM DocumentTable PD2 ....WHERE PD2.DATECOLUMN > PD.DATECOLUMN).
```

One speedup advantage here is we don't *really* care about `ORDER BY`, we just want to make sure we have the newest row in pd (we use the not-exists stuff with pd2 to kick any older pd records out of the running).

The reason I think this can be faster than an `ORDER BY` is the SQL Server engine doesn't need to do an index traversal to handle the `TOP 1` on an `ORDER BY DATECOLUMN DESC`"; a clever optimizer could maybe figure that out and just jumping to the maximum index on DATECOLUMN... but that is a big maybe so I expect this approach to be faster overall).

You'll note a similar trick that blocks block any PD record where it has a DC1 or DC2.

In the original query I read that part (at the end, in the main WHERE clause) to mean: "Even if a given PD record is perfect in every way (perfectly matches 's' and is the newest PD record), if any PD/S matches exist with 'DC1' or 'DC2' (whatever the dates) then we want to kick out ALL PD/S records.